# Python: Executing selected statements

Tags: python, python-idle

I am new to python programming... Just wanted to know does IDLE has a concept of 'executing selected statements'?? 
F5 runs the whole program... Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Paste the statements of choice into the shell that appears when you hit F5. Aside from that, there's no real way to execute specific lines you might identify in the editor window

Comment: try to learn IPython too, and install PyQt (or PySide) and Tornado, you will have then, a wonderful visual console, or juste Spyder, you will get everything you want!

Answer (score 0):

No, not now.  Since you are at least the second person to ask this, I added the idea to my personal list of possible enhancements.  However, while running a selection would not be a problem, producing accurate tracebacks for exception would be.  Doing so is an essential part of Python's operation.

Currently, one can disable code that you need to not run by commenting it out (Alt-F3) or by making it a string.  One can stop execution after a particular statement by adding `1/0`.  Or you can copy code to a new editor window.

Do you have a specific use case in mind, or are you just wondering?

Answer (score -1):

Install [Spyder](https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/downloads), with its [dependecies](http://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html#installing-or-running-directly-from-source), and you will have wonderful **FREE IDE** !

[image: spyder interface]

You will have another solution, is to use IPython Notebook, where you will be able to use your Internet Browser to run python codes!:

[image: notebook]

Comment: people like to downvote just because they are this option enabled! and the worse, they do it anonymously! at least show why you do it!